# Проверка отправки формы Wordpress/Divi

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть сайт на Wordpress (на конструкторе Divi), при отправке формы надо выводить попап "спасибо за обращение". У формы есть встроенный валидатор, к коду которого у меня нет доступа. Нашёл такой способ обработки (сам в коде — слаб), но он срабатывает каждый раз при клике на отправить, даже если форма не заполнена и валидатор выдаёт ошибку. Подскажите, есть ли способ какого-то "перехвата события" отправки корректно заполненной формы?

```
<script> 
jQuery(".et_pb_contact_form").submit(function( event ) {
PUM.open(1359);});
</script>
```

PUM.open(1359) — открывает попап окно с тем самым "Спасибо".

Answer (score 0):

Разрулил путём "вторичной валидации" — просто ещё раз роверил поля.
Скорее всего код ламерский, но работает...)))

```
 <script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( '.et_pb_contact_form' ).submit(function( event ) {
         var x=document.getElementById('et_pb_contact_name_0').value;
         var x1=document.getElementById('et_pb_contact_phone_number_0').value;
         var x2=document.getElementById('et_pb_contact_email_0').value;
         var x3=document.getElementById('et_pb_contact_message_0').value;

        if (x.length!=0){
            if (x1.length!=0){
               if (x2.length!=0){
                  if (x3.length!=0){
                               PUM.open(1359);
                  }     
               }                 
             }
          }
        });
      }); 
    });
    </script>
```